# No idea why my validators aren't working

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am new to html and javascript. I encountered a problem which seems correct but it doesn't work. There must be in problem in the function, which i can't figure it out.

```html
<html>
<body>
  <section>
    <form name="CombinationWithRep">
      <h2>Combination with repetition</h2>
      N:<input type="text" name="numberOfThings" /> R:
      <input type="text" name="selection" />
      <button onclick="CombinationWithRepfun()">Sub</button>
      <p id="demo1"></p>
    </form>
    <script langauge="javascript">
      function CombinationWithRepfun() {
        var number = document.forms["CombinationWithRep"]["numberOfThings"].value;
        var selector = document.forms["CombinationWithRep"]["selection"].value;
        if (number == " ") {
          alert("pleas typo");
          return false;
        }
        if (selector == " ") {
          alert("pleas typo");
          return false;
        }
        var number1 = number * 1;
        var selector1 = selector * 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.pow(number1, selector1);

      }
    </script>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `document.getElementById("demo")`. It should be `demo1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

1. You are checking the value with a space (), which I think you didn't wanted. You have to check the value with empty string.
2. You can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the event from further execution if the condition is true.
3. You should execute other code if the condition is false.
4. You also have to use `demo1` instead of `demo`. Try the following code:

```html
<form name="CombinationWithRep">
  <h2>Combination with repetition</h2>
  N:<input type="text" name="numberOfThings"/>
  R:<input type="text" name="selection"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="CombinationWithRepfun(event)">Sub</button>
  <p id="demo1"></p>
  </form>
  <script langauge="javascript">
    function CombinationWithRepfun(e) {
      var number = document.forms["CombinationWithRep"]["numberOfThings"].value;
      var selector = document.forms["CombinationWithRep"]["selection"].value;
      if (number.trim() == "" || selector.trim() == "") {
        alert("pleas typo");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
        var number1 = number*1;
        var selector1 = selector*1;
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = Math.pow(number1, selector1);
      }

    }
  </script>
</section>
```

Comment: hi there, your solution works but i dont want the program to open a new page. so how can i do that/

Comment: @devpatel, when the program open a new page?........can you explain little bit detail?

Comment: what i mean is once i submit the value, the score should stay there and not open a new page.

Comment: @devpatel, I think I have understood the problem....just change the button type like `type="button"`...I have already updated the answer......please check.....

Answer (score 0):

First, typo in your script tag ("language" not "langauge".)
Second I think you need to convert number1 and selector1 from strings to numbers with parseInt or ParseFloat

Answer (score 0):

Answers are below and here's how I would build that: https://codepen.io/yamato79/pen/YjwzQE hope this helps, have a nice day.

- Add type="button" `<button type="button" onclick="CombinationWithRepfun()">Sub</button>` attribute so it doesn't submit the form when you click on the button. It keeps refreshing the page everytime you click the button because it's submitting the form to the same page.
- `if (selector == "")` `if (number == "")` Compare it with just quotes. You used " " which is not equal to the input being empty.
- Change `<script langauge="javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">`
- `document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = Math.pow(number1, selector1);` And lastly, your element ID was incorrect.